# Is goodwill necessary in order to make progress on the Path?

Tags: theravada

It seems impossible to have goodwill in certain situations. Is it enough to be tolerant and forgiving of other's faults?

Comment: right intention is part the 8-fold path. compassion is well known to be the motivator in bodhisattva progress. HTH :-)

Comment: if you mean consummation, rather than progress: arhats lack certain "emotions", I believe (that is one way for us to think about the defilements), whereas bodhisattvas would, I suppose, be aware they are transient and empty. all the best!

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://www.dhammatalks.org/books/BeyondAllDirections/Section0007.html) essay on goodwill helpful, particularly the excerpt below:

> "... you wish not only that beings be happy, but also that they avoid
> the actions that would lead to bad karma, to their own unhappiness.
> You realize that happiness has to depend on action: For people to find
> true happiness, they have to understand the causes for happiness and
> act on them. They also have to understand that true happiness is
> harmless. If it depends on something that harms others, it’s not going
> to last. Those who are harmed are sure to do what they can to destroy
> that happiness. And then there’s the plain quality of sympathy: If you
> see someone suffering, it’s painful. If you have any sensitivity at
> all, it’s hard to feel happy when you know that your happiness is
> causing suffering for others.
>
> So again, when you express goodwill, you’re not saying that you’re
> going to be there for them all the time. You’re hoping that all beings
> will wise up about how to find happiness and be there for themselves."

Answer (score -2):

Surely it's nearly impossible for one not familar to the Dhamma of the Sublime Buddha, good householder. Maybe good to start to investigate it via [metta here](https://sangham.net/en/dictionary/mett%C4%81) and especially the essays. For intensive and benefical, good to [leave home and commercial places first](https://forum.sangham.net/index.php?action=forum).